# How to push object to key array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have an object like this:

```
var newService = new Service({
     name: service.name,
     description: service.description,
     supplier: service.supplier,
     price: service.price,
     info_requires: []
});
```

Here is modal `Service`

```
var serviceSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    supplier: String,
    price: Number,
    info_requires: [{
        name: String,
        type: Number, // 1-text 2-combobox 3-textarea
        limit: []
    }],
});
```

Here is my data:

`var services = [{
            name: "Test",
            description: "Des",
            supplier: "Sup",
            price: 123,
            icon: "icon",
            type: 1,
            open: 1,
            info_requires: [
                {
                    name: "Age",
                    type: 1,
                    limit: []
                },
                {
                    name: "Bla bla",
                    type: 1,
                    limit: []
                }
            ]
        }]`

I push data to `info_requires[]` like this:

```
newService.info_requires.push(service.info_requires[i])
```

or

`newService.info_requires[i].name = (service.info_requires[i].name)`
But it did not work with error: `Cannot set property &#39;name&#39; of undefined`? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Is **some_object** defined?

Comment: Would be nice if you could give some more context on the `Service` constructor.

Comment: Looks like a mix of literal and constructor

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Do you get any errors in the console, or does *something* happen but the wrong thing, or...?

Comment: @Jerry Here is my `Service` :

`var serviceSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        description: String,
        supplier: String,
        price: 100,
        info_requires: [{
            name: String,
            type: Number, // 1-text 2-combobox 3-textarea
            limit: []
        }],
    });`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional code there, so that it can be properly formatted.

Comment: @nnnnnnn I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In case the "Service" is a custom Object created by you, this might do the trick

```
var service ={
 name: "",
 description: "",
 supplier: "",
 price: "",
 info_requires: []
};

service.info_requires.push(some_object);
new Service(service);
```

Comment: But...what if the OP needs whatever other features the `Service()` constructor provides?

Comment: he can still create a `new Service(service)` because it is an object with correct properties

Answer (score 0):

Check if the key exists first, if not create a array/object for the key like

```
if (newService.info_requires === undefined) {
    newService.info_requires = [];
}
newService.info_requires.push(service.info_requires[i]);
```

Similar for

```
if (newService.info_requires[i] === undefined) {
    newService.info_requires[i] = {};
}
newService.info_requires[i].name = (service.info_requires[i].name);
```